# sql query to Display the table in html format using sql server

Tags: html, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table like this:

```
create table testjob
(
  jobid int,  
  jobname varchar(100),  
  time float,  
  name varchar(50)  
)
```

and sample data in that table:

```
insert into testjob values ( 1001,'java work',4.5,'arjun')   
insert into testjob values ( 1005,'sql work',10,'arjun')  
insert into testjob values ( 1010,'.net work',7.5,'arjun')  
insert into testjob values ( 1040,'java work',5.5,'ravi')  
insert into testjob values ( 1023,'php work',2.5,'arjun')  
insert into testjob values ( 1027,'.net work',3.5,'ravi')
```

I want to create a procedure so that my output is as below in the html format like below that is in sql

we will write select * from testjob but i want the output to be displayed in html using stored procedure or so

```
Name    Jobname     Time

arjun   Javawork     4.5  
arjun   sql work     10  
arjun   .net work    7.5  
ravi     java work   5.5   
arjun    php work    2.5  
ravi     .net work   3.5
```

Comment: SQL Server is about storing and fetching data - formatting as HTML is **not** SQL Server's job. Let SQL Server return the **data** needed for your page - and let your HTML part (ASP.NET or whatever you're using) do the HTML formatting.

Comment: Why would you want to format the data in SQL? Much better off returning the data to your application and letting it sort out the formatting. If you do need something formatted from SQL, you could try FOR XML AUTO

Comment: @marc I take it you don't send HTML formatted emails directly from SQL Server then

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: nope - no way.

Comment: @marc Well, it works and is a valid use case. I see it everywhere I go.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, returning a vanilla table/tr/td form of the data.

```
select
    '<table>'+
    (
    select '<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+jobname+'</td><td>'+cast(time as varchar(10))+'</td>'
    from testjob
    for xml path(''),root('a'),type
    ).value('(/a)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    +'</table>';
```

Now, if you wanted some specific ordering of the rows, you'll add an `ORDER BY` before the FOR XML line.